# Changing time zone is not working

Tags: php, joomla, timezone

How to change the default time zone to CET time zone in our Joomla website. We use the PHP function

`ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Rome');`

but still get one hour difference (ahead).

Please let me know what ideas you guys may have on fixing this.

Could this one hour difference have something to do with summer time off set?

Comment: Have you tried with `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');` ?

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I know nothing about Joomla or PHP.*

I *do* however, know how to Google for `joomla timezone` and  `joomla daylight savings`

According to the [Joomla Documentation](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/51/153/1/2/), the Joomla settings only support a simple offset.

Others have [asked about supporting DST/Summer time](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2118717), and the interim solution is to [use this plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/hosting-a-servers/servers/9268).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");
```

Else if you can try

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
echo $now->format('g:i A');
```

that depends on your requirement.